# TypeError: this.html is undefined in Reactjs ( Problem with renderHTML )

Tags: reactjs, frontend, next.js, mern

I tried creating a blog referring to a github repository there is a feature to load blogs using one load more button to load blogs when there is more than 2 and I did that. and it's showing an error in node_modules folder which I didn't open. I tried **cache clean** but nothing happened.

```
TypeError: this.html is undefined

./node_modules/parse5/lib/tokenizer/preprocessor.js/Preprocessor.prototype.write

./node_modules/parse5/lib/tokenizer/preprocessor.js:91

  88 |     else
  89 |         this.html = chunk;
  90 | 
> 91 |     this.lastCharPos = this.html.length - 1;
  92 |     this.endOfChunkHit = false;
  93 |     this.lastChunkWritten = isLastChunk;
  94 | };
```

Can someone suggest a solution.

Error Screenshot:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9jiS.png ]

GitHub repository link:https://github.com/aravind33/Almost-Everything

Comment: Try deleting node_modules and package.json.lock then `npm update` && `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The actual problem was in **renderHTML** npm package as it has not been updated so I tried using **striptags** and it worked fine.

So basically instead of `<div>{renderHTML(blog.excerpt)}</div>`

I used  `<div>{striptags(blog.excerpt)}</div>` and it worked fine